# How to use Query using regex in Node js (mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot seem to wrap my head around how regex works for Mongoose in Node js. I have looked through some of the regex examples on different websites and on Stackoverflow. Is regex with `find()` not usable for an object with multiple properties? If so, must I use aggregate instead and how should I go about using it?

I am trying to query for documents that return date === "June" where "June" is a substring.

```
Model.find({ 'meta': { 'date':  { $regex: '.*June.', $options: 'i'} } })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(`[*csv metadata 2*] Data: ${data}`);
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(`error: ${error}`);
        });
```

I have also tried `Model.find({ 'meta': { 'date':  { $regex: /.*June./, $options: 'i'} } })`, none of which worked.

Mongodb structure

```
"meta": {
    "products": {
      "bolder": {
        "ver": "v1.0",
        "csv": "filePath"
      },
      "rock": {
        "ver": "v1.0",
        "csv": "filePath"
      },
      "stone": {
        "ver": "v1.0",
        "csv": "filePath"
      },
      "mountain": {
        "ver": "v1.0",
        "csv": "filePath"
      }
    },
    "date": "20 June 2022",
    "env": "Indoor",
    "desc": "This is a comment in the textarea."
  }
```

Comment: Use the nested field name as `""meta.date"`. Try to understand what regex characters like `.` and `*` mean - and use them appropriately.

Comment: @prasad_ How do you think I should go about writing the `$regex`? I have already tried `Model.find({ 'meta.date':  { $regex: /.*June./, $options: 'i'} } })` before, it still returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely theoretical...

first just grab the collection...

Secondly create a new list with aggregated data...

The data should have the field you're searching for including a ref to the main obj

i.e `const data ={ "Id" : "doc_id", "Date" : "June 22", "Other" : "relevant fields" }`

Search the new list,

to optimize...you can also add some fields to this new object for data you don't want to refetch by querying the entire the OG collection objects

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).